# How to sort words by frequency in a csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have .csv files that look like this but I can't figure out how to read and sort by frequency the words of the first paragraph of the file, it looks like this:

[image]

I only want to sort the selected lines which have a length of 'total_lines' that I already calculate elsewhere. I have tried this code but it doesn't give me the result I need:

```
from collections import Counter

y = open(filename, 'r', newline='')
print(collections.Counter(y))
```

I have also tried using the csv reader but couldn't manage either.

This is part of the file:

```
UserScreenNameUserNameTimestampTextEmbedded_textEmojisCommentsLikesRetweetsImage,linkTweet,URLAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,Los,Reyes,Magos,ya,están,repartiendo,ilusión,por,#,Calvià,#,CabalgataDeReyesAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
en,eLos,Reyes,magos,repartirán,más,de,kg,de,caramelos,#,SinGlúten,en,la,Gran,#,Cabalgata,de,CalviàNos,vemos,a,las,h,en,Palmanova,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,Buena,acogida,de,la,campaña,de,identificación,y,esterilización,de,el,gato,doméstico,en,CalviàAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,ha,extraído,unastoneladas,de,#residuossólidos,de,las,estaciones,de,bombeo,de,aguas,residuales,de,#,Calvià,(,EBAR,),durante,las,tareas,de,limpieza,en,profundidad,de,estas,instalacionesAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,Fotos,de,la,Gran,Cabalgata,de,#,Calvià,#IlusiónAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,Primera,presentación,de,el,avance,de,el,PGOU,de,#,Calvià,a,la,ciudadanía,#,Participación,#,Transparencia,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,Reunión,de,la,Alianza,deMunicipios,Turísticos,de,Sol,y,Playa,en,Fitur,Seguimos,trabajando,para,mejorar,nuestro,destino,#,Turismo,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,Entrega,de,premios,ITH,Smart,Destination,Awards,de,en,#FITUR,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,El,teniente,alcalde,de,turismo,se,reúne,con,el,director,de,la,oficina,española,de,turismo,en,Frankfurt,#,FiturAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,Seguimos,en,#,Fitur,trabajando,para,promocionar,#,Calvià,como,un,destino,lleno,de,oportunidades,durante,todo,el,año,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,En,#FITUR,entrevista,a,para,hablar,de,#,TurismoAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,ha,saludado,a,el,alumnado,de,Turismo,de,el,IES,Calvià,en,#,FiturAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,En,la,agenda,deencontrarás,todas,las,actividades,que,se,realizan,en,el,municipioNo,te,pierdas,nada,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià

UserScreenNameUserNameTimestampTextEmbedded_textEmojisCommentsLikesRetweetsImage,linkTweet,URLAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,el,Reyes,Magos,ya,estar,repartir,ilusión,por,#,Calvià,#,CabalgataDeReyesAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
en,eLos,Reyes,mago,repartir,más,de,kg,de,caramelo,#,SinGlúten,en,el,Gran,#,Cabalgata,de,CalviàNos,ver,a,el,h,en,Palmanova,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,buen,acogida,de,el,campaña,de,identificación,y,esterilización,de,el,gato,doméstico,en,CalviàAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,haber,extraer,unastonelado,de,#residuossólidos,de,el,estación,de,bombeo,de,agua,residual,de,#,Calvià,(,EBAR,),durante,el,tarea,de,limpieza,en,profundidad,de,este,instalacionesAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,Fotos,de,el,Gran,Cabalgata,de,#,Calvià,#IlusiónAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,primero,presentación,de,el,avance,de,el,PGOU,de,#,Calvià,a,el,ciudadanía,#,Participación,#,Transparencia,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,Reunión,de,el,Alianza,deMunicipios,Turísticos,de,Sol,y,Playa,en,Fitur,seguir,trabajar,para,mejorar,nuestro,destino,#,Turismo,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,Entrega,de,premio,ITH,Smart,Destination,Awards,de,en,#FITUR,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,el,teniente,alcalde,de,turismo,él,reunir,con,el,director,de,el,oficina,español,de,turismo,en,Frankfurt,#,FiturAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,seguir,en,#,Fitur,trabajar,para,promocionar,#,Calvià,como,uno,destino,lleno,de,oportunidad,durante,todo,el,año,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,en,#FITUR,entrevista,a,para,hablar,de,#,TurismoAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,haber,saludar,a,el,alumnado,de,Turismo,de,el,IES,Calvià,en,#,FiturAjuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià
ene,en,el,agenda,deencontrar,todo,el,actividad,que,él,realizar,en,el,municipioNo,tú,perder,nada,Ajuntament,de,Calvià,de,Calvià

PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
ADP,DET,PROPN,PROPN,ADV,AUX,VERB,NOUN,ADP,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
ADP,PROPN,PROPN,NOUN,VERB,ADV,ADP,NUM,ADP,NOUN,NOUN,PROPN,ADP,DET,ADJ,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,VERB,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADP,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PUNCT,ADJ,NOUN,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADP,NOUN,CCONJ,NOUN,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADJ,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PROPN,AUX,VERB,ADJ,ADP,NOUN,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADP,NOUN,ADP,NOUN,ADJ,ADP,PROPN,PROPN,PUNCT,PROPN,PUNCT,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADP,NOUN,ADP,NOUN,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PROPN,PROPN,ADP,DET,ADJ,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PUNCT,ADJ,NOUN,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADP,DET,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,DET,NOUN,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PUNCT,PROPN,ADP,DET,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,CCONJ,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,VERB,VERB,ADP,VERB,DET,NOUN,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PROPN,PROPN,ADP,NOUN,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,ADP,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PUNCT,DET,NOUN,NOUN,ADP,NOUN,PRON,VERB,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADJ,ADP,NOUN,ADP,PROPN,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PUNCT,VERB,ADP,NOUN,PROPN,VERB,ADP,VERB,NOUN,PROPN,SCONJ,DET,NOUN,ADJ,ADP,NOUN,ADP,DET,DET,NOUN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PUNCT,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADP,ADP,VERB,ADP,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PROPN,AUX,VERB,ADP,DET,NOUN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,DET,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN
PUNCT,ADP,DET,NOUN,VERB,DET,DET,NOUN,PRON,PRON,VERB,ADP,DET,NOUN,PRON,VERB,PRON,PROPN,ADP,PROPN,ADP,PROPN

,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
```

Expected output should be something like:

```
[('word1', freq1), ('word2', freq2), ('word3', freq3)...]
```

Comment: What counts as a "word"?

Comment: @PranavHosangadi everything separated by ','

Comment: Why do you expect individual words or a subset of the file to be counted when you asked `collections.Counter` to work on the whole file? A first step would be to read the file using the `csv` module, which will give you individual rows and columns of the CSV, and then count. You say you _"tried using the csv reader but couldn't manage"_, but _what did you try_, and _what does "couldn't manage" mean specifically?_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the task is to read CSV file from second line to first occurrence of empty line and count all words.

To read CSV file you can use built-in [`csv.reader()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader). Basically returned `reader` is an [*iterator*](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) which yields list of columns from every line, so to skip first line we can just call [`next()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) once. We can manually iterate over reader until it returns empty list or apply [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile) with [`operator.truth()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.truth). To pass all words directly into [`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) constructor we can apply [`chain.from_iterable()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) which will flatten lists returned from `takewhile()`. To get result sorted by frequency we can use [`Counter.most_common()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common).

**Code:**

```py
import csv
from itertools import takewhile, chain
from operator import truth
from collections import Counter

with open(r"CSV_100.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    next(reader)  # skip first line
    counter = Counter(chain.from_iterable(takewhile(truth, reader)))
print(*counter.most_common())
```

**Output:**

```
('de', 55) ('CalviÃ\xa0', 32) ('#', 15) ('ene', 12) ('en', 11) ('el', 8) ('la', 7) ('Ajuntament', 6) ('a', 4) ('las', 4) ('para', 3) ('Reyes', 2) ('Gran', 2) ('Cabalgata', 2) ('y', 2) ('ha', 2) ('durante', 2) ('Fitur', 2) ('Seguimos', 2) ('trabajando', 2) ('destino', 2) ('Turismo', 2) ('#FITUR', 2) ('turismo', 2) ('se', 2) ('FiturAjuntament', 2) ('En', 2) ('Los', 1) ('Magos', 1) ('ya', 1) ('estÃ¡n', 1) ('repartiendo', 1) ('ilusiÃ³n', 1) ('por', 1) ('CabalgataDeReyesAjuntament', 1) ('eLos', 1) ('magos', 1) ('repartirÃ¡n', 1) ('mÃ¡s', 1) ('kg', 1) ('caramelos', 1) ('SinGlÃºten', 1) ('CalviÃ\xa0Nos', 1) ('vemos', 1) ('h', 1) ('Palmanova', 1) ('Buena', 1) ('acogida', 1) ('campaÃ±a', 1) ('identificaciÃ³n', 1) ('esterilizaciÃ³n', 1) ('gato', 1) ('domÃ©stico', 1) ('CalviÃ\xa0Ajuntament', 1) ('extraÃ\xaddo', 1) ('unastoneladas', 1) ('#residuossÃ³lidos', 1) ('estaciones', 1) ('bombeo', 1) ('aguas', 1) ('residuales', 1) ('(', 1) ('EBAR', 1) (')', 1) ('tareas', 1) ('limpieza', 1) ('profundidad', 1) ('estas', 1) ('instalacionesAjuntament', 1) ('Fotos', 1) ('#IlusiÃ³nAjuntament', 1) ('Primera', 1) ('presentaciÃ³n', 1) ('avance', 1) ('PGOU', 1) ('ciudadanÃ\xada', 1) ('ParticipaciÃ³n', 1) ('Transparencia', 1) ('ReuniÃ³n', 1) ('Alianza', 1) ('deMunicipios', 1) ('TurÃ\xadsticos', 1) ('Sol', 1) ('Playa', 1) ('mejorar', 1) ('nuestro', 1) ('Entrega', 1) ('premios', 1) ('ITH', 1) ('Smart', 1) ('Destination', 1) ('Awards', 1) ('El', 1) ('teniente', 1) ('alcalde', 1) ('reÃºne', 1) ('con', 1) ('director', 1) ('oficina', 1) ('espaÃ±ola', 1) ('Frankfurt', 1) ('promocionar', 1) ('como', 1) ('un', 1) ('lleno', 1) ('oportunidades', 1) ('todo', 1) ('aÃ±o', 1) ('entrevista', 1) ('hablar', 1) ('TurismoAjuntament', 1) ('saludado', 1) ('alumnado', 1) ('IES', 1) ('agenda', 1) ('deencontrarÃ¡s', 1) ('todas', 1) ('actividades', 1) ('que', 1) ('realizan', 1) ('municipioNo', 1) ('te', 1) ('pierdas', 1) ('nada', 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like

```py
words = []
with open('data.csv','r') as file:
    while line:=file.readline().rstrip(): #stop on end file or double new line
        words += line.split(',')
freq = {}
for word in set(words): 
    freq[word] = words.count(word)

print(freq)

print(sorted(freq.items(),key=lambda item:item[1]))
```

Your .csv also seems to have a bunch of typos, in case that's an issue you didn't catch yet.

Comment: Also `lambda item:item[1]` could be replaced with [`itemgetter(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter).

Comment: it returnrs '\n' endlessly, if I use @OlvinRoght 's line instead it returns this:

https://imgur.com/a/Yv9yzVy

Wich is the paragraph I want sorted by frequency but it's not sorting it